# Create a type from value of one property in an array of objects

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to extract a particular property of a union type and create a type from that?

Let's say we have this:

```
type Actions =
  | {
  type: "ADD_COLUMN";
  newColumnIndex: number;
  column: SelectorColumnData;
}
  | {
  type: "ITEM_CHECKED";
  columnIndex: number;
  item: SelectorItem;
};
```

Is there some magic generic stuff we can use to produce something like:

```
type ActionTypes = GetTypes<Actions>
// ActionTypes = "ADD_COLUMN" | "ITEM_CHECKED"
```

Comment: `Actions["type"]` - However, if one of the constituents of `Actions` does not have a `type` property, it'll be a little more complicated. You would have to extract all constituents first: `Extract<Actions, { type: any }>["type"]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all possible values of a key from union of objects by just accessing a property from the type. As mentioned in the comments it can be done using :

```
Action["type"];
```

But if you really want to create a type. You will have to use extends too, so TS can let you safely access the property.

```
type Actions =
  | {
  type: "ADD_COLUMN";
  newColumnIndex: number;
  column: string;
}
  | {
  type: "ITEM_CHECKED";
  columnIndex: number;
  item: string;
};

type GetTypes<T extends { type : string }> =  T['type'];


type ActionTypes = GetTypes<Actions>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=37&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYGcoF4BQUoA+UA3nlKJAFxQBEMAIvQPoDCA8gDICqAsgHI0A3GVQQA7i2QAbAK4BbVAElUAEwgAPaqnkAjCACdh+ONPmpq6YPsSoA5sIC+ZIqXwUI1GooAqAUR6sABK+LADSvvRCZCayCspqmlDacnqGZIjAEHIWVjb2OA7COO5QAOIQwN7gEOgAPN5QGpmqmMTk1VA51nZQDgB82PjeANoA5O6jALpFxR3wSGhVkJhYZRVLNbXzKBh9QA)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer elsewhere. Doesn't even require generics:

```
type ActionTypes = Actions["type"];
```